# How to solve "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"? Will not run on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

When trying to start XAMPP I get the following:

```
[mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:02:20  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:02:20  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:02:20  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:02:20  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:02:20  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:02:20  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Copy of logs:

```
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT at 41802377 between the checkpoint 41802377 and the end 41802240.
2022-09-15 11:02:19 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2022-09-15 11:02:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-09-15 11:02:20 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-09-15 11:02:20 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-09-15 11:02:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-15 11:02:20 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-09-15 11:02:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

PHP-My Admin errors:

```
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Could anyone help me resolve?

Comment: remove these files and restart `rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0` 
`rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1`

Comment: Thanks, i found creating a new data folder within xxamp/mysql and migrating the backup db files worked

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to xampp/mysql directory
2. Rename the /data folder to /data_old
3. Copy the /backup folder and paste right here
4. Rename the /backup_copy folder to /data
5. Go to /data_old folder and copy all your database folder expect phpmyadmin, mysql, performance_schema
6. Go to /data folder and paste all database folder copied from /data_old
7. Go to /data_old folder again and copy ibdata1 file
8. Go to /data folder again and paste ibdata1 file here
9. Restart your server again.

Comment: i am sorry this looks hillaurious to read..... but it will help you

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to xampp
2. And then Mysql Directory
3. Rename the **data** folder to some other name e.g data_old
4. Copy the **backup folder** and rename the folder with **data**
5. Copy the databases from old data folder to new data folder
6. Copy the log files **ibdata1 && ib_logfileXX** from old folder to new data folder.
7. Restart the MySQL server.

That's it!

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks. Just make sure you do not overwrite any of the default database files that is inside the backup folder - only your own databases  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution is the one proposed by Vel in the comment to the question. You can also rename the files instead of deleting them.

> remove these files and restart rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 –

In XAMPP those files are located at: \xampp\mysql\data. In my case, C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0 and C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1